# How to generate files with a custom module and PHP?

Tags: php, file, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I have a site with Drupal 8. I have created a custom module. Here is its code :

https://github.com/S1BIOSE/generator_website

generator-website-page.html.twig :

```
<div class="card mb-5 overflow-hidden shadow rounded bg-white">
  <div class="card-body">
   
    <form>

      <legend>Générateur de site web</legend>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="TokenUrl" class="form-label">L'URL de votre site web</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="TokenUrl" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Ce champ est requis.
        </div>
        <small id="helpUrl" class="form-text">Entrez l'URL complète de votre site web.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="TokenTitle" class="form-label">Nom de l'entreprise</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="TokenTitle" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Ce champ est requis.
        </div>
        <small id="helpTitle" class="form-text">Entrez le nom de votre entreprise.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="TokenDescription" class="form-label">Présentation de l'entreprise</label>
        <textarea class="form-control is-invalid" id="TokenDescription" rows="5" required></textarea>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Ce champ est requis.
        </div>
        <small id="helpDescription" class="form-text">Entrez une description de votre entreprise.</small>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="TokenFeed" class="form-label">Fil d'actualité</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TokenFeed">
        <small id="helpFeed" class="form-text">Entrez l'url de votre Flux RSS sur la plateforme S1BIOSE.</small>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Générer</button>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

What should I put in my module to generate the 3 files above and replace the words starting with Token ?

In this custom module, I created a form with IDs (I'm not sure if this is the right way to go). For example, the data entered in the TokenTitle field must replace TokenTitle wherever it appears in the files.

When a user submits the form, it must download the 3 files with the correct data (the one entered in the form). If possible in a ZIP archive.

It is unnecessary to keep the information submitted in the form in the database.

manifest.json

```
{
  "orientation":"portrait",
  "short_name": "TokenTitle",
  "name": "TokenTitle",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "description": "TokenDescription",
  "lang": "fr",
  "icons": [{
        "src": "icon-144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any maskable"
      }, {
        "src": "icon-192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any maskable"
      }, {
        "src": "icon-512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any maskable"
      }],
  "start_url": "/?source=pwa",
  "scope": "/"
}
```

sitemap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>TokenUrl/index.html</loc>
<lastmod>TokenDate</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

sw.js

```
const staticCacheName = 'TokenTimestamp';
const filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html',
  '/CHANGELOG.md',
  '/bootstrap.min.css',
  '/style.css',
  '/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
  '/popover.js',
  '/clipboard.min.js',
  '/btn-clipboard.js',
  '/pwa.js',
  '/feed.js',
  '/toasts.js',
  '/icon-32.png',
  '/icon-144.png',
  '/icon-192.png',
  '/icon-512.png',
  '/iphone5_splash.png',
  '/iphone6_splash.png',
  '/iphoneplus_splash.png',
  '/iphonex_splash.png',
  '/iphonexr_splash.png',
  '/iphonexsmax_splash.png',
  '/ipad_splash.png',
  '/ipadpro1_splash.png',
  '/ipadpro3_splash.png',
  '/ipadpro2_splash.png'
];

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
    return Promise.all(
      cacheNames.filter(function(staticCacheName) {
      }).map(function(staticCacheName) {
        return caches.delete(staticCacheName);
      })
    );
  }));
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(cachedResponse => {
      if (cachedResponse) {
        return cachedResponse;
      }
      return fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  if (event.data.action === 'skipWaiting') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use standard PHP to make the file, as then you'll need to handle housekeeping/ removing it/ managing it as well.  Drupal has [BinaryFileResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21BinaryFileResponse.php/function/BinaryFileResponse%3A%3A__construct/8.9.x) for sending files to users and [\Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!File!FileSystemInterface.php/interface/FileSystemInterface/8.8.x) for creation/ management of files.  If it is temporary, then simply set it [as this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21FileInterface.php/function/FileInterface%3A%3AsetTemporary/8.9.x).

Comment: Thanks, yes I don't want to keep the data and files, after the user (ananyme or registered) downloads the ZIP archive. I am new to drupal custom modules and I do not know how to use PHP. What should I add to my current mod please ?

Answer (score -1):

Hello ok  there are the things you will need to know how todo do:

1. Learn how to make files with php: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp
2. learn how Drupal routing and controllers work:
   https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example
3. learn how Drupal handles forms https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/introduction-to-form-api

once you know  these things then you can use on form submit
some php to generate your files and then probably group them for download ...or what ever your doing with them.

Comment: It sounds complicated. My form is here (it is created with Bootstrap) https://www.s1biose.com/fr/generator-website It is not possible to match the IDs of the fields of the form with the words starting with "Token" in the files ? If not, wouldn't it be easier to create tokens ?

Comment: As taggartJ says, you should use Drupals form API to create the form - as it'll protect you from potential XSS and CSRF attacks (and other reasons).

Comment: @Pobtastic Even if I don't want to save the forms to the database ?

Comment: It's not about saving the forms to the database, it's about protecting the forms from being utilised by malicious users.